# Add HttpHandler registration in web.config in runtime

Tags: iis, permissions, web-config, httphandler

I was trying to add some configuration in web.config file after the web page is started up. Such as:

But when I deploy it to the IIS, there of course has an authority issue to modify the web.config file. So I need add everyone permission to this application in IIS.

My question is: could any one give me a clue that I can add this configuration in runtime without the everyone permission? Such as adding this configuration to memory?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have a workaround to register the httphandler to web.config in the OnPreRender life-circle and it works fine; but the bad thing is that when we deploy it, we need give it a higher privilege. If you have better idea, please share it.